# i just started learning about classes and there is a random syntax error that i cannot understand

Tags: python

```
class Car:

  def __init__(self, model, yearmade):
   self.yearmade = yearmade
   self.model = model


  def vroom(self):
    print(str(model) + "goes vroom")

Car1 = Car("passat", 2012)
print(Car1.model, car1.yearmade)
car1.vroom
```

the shell says on the 3rd line from bottom, the C at the beginning is a syntax error

edit: also the vroom function does not work, even if i just make it print "vroom"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your syntax error when copying the code. Make sure that you have closed all parentheses at the line preceding the error. Also, `car1` and `Car1` are different names. Finally, to call a function or method you need brackets after its name.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing self on your `vroom` method. Update it like this:

```
  def vroom(self):
    print(str(self.model) + "goes vroom")
```

and you have to call your method with parenthesis:

```
Car1.vroom()
```

Then formatting strings that way is very "unpythonic". This is better:

```
  def vroom(self):
     print("{} goes vroom".format(self.model))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To access the value of an object inside the class you have to do it via the `self` object. In your case, `self.model`. `self` and `Car1` are both the same object.
2. Python is case sensitive. `Car1` and `car1` are different variables. In your case, `car1` must be renamed to `Car1` to work.
3. To call a function you need to add parenthesis. `Car1.vroom()`. If the function has parameters you would add them inside. But even without parameters, you need the parentheses.